# WPF datagrid cursor doesn't change on column resize

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, resize

I have encoutnered a bug that I can't make the source out of, so I wanted to ask if anyone has encountered something similar.
The setup is simply:

```
        <Grid>
            <DataGrid>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test1" Width="100"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test2" Width="100"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test3" Width="100"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
```

There of course is more code after the datagrid, but at no point I implement any Styles or Themes or interact with the datagrid in any way, shape or form and it would be to much code to include it all.
When I hover over the split line between columns then the mouse cursor doesn't change to the resize cursor with the 2 arrows (Cursors.SizeWE).
It still works and resizes fine if I click and drag and works as expected in any other regard.

In this setup I have a style, but only for my button and here it just can't be resized at all:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid_main" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test1" Width="100"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test2" Width="100"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test3" Width="100"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <DockPanel Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
            <Button x:Name="btn_loadSchema" Content="Load Schema" Grid.Row="0" Height="20" Width="85" DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
                        Margin="5" Click="LoadSchema" Style="{StaticResource ModernButtonTheme}"/>
            <Button x:Name="btn_loadJSON" Content="Load JSON" Grid.Row="0" Height="20" Width="85" DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                        Margin="5" Click="LoadJSON" Style="{StaticResource ModernButtonTheme}" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <Button x:Name="btn_saveJSON" Content="Save JSON" Grid.Row="0" Height="20" Width="85" DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                        Margin="5" Click="SaveJSON" Style="{StaticResource ModernButtonTheme}" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <Label/>
        </DockPanel>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid x:Name="grid_content" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            </Grid>
         </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to copy your first XAML snippet into a blank WPF project? Can you reproduce the issue then? I doubt it because I cannot.

As for your second snippet, you should either remove the `ScrollViewer` or move it to another row by adding another `RowDefinition` to the `Grid` and increase the value of `Grid.Row` attached property. Currently, it lays on top of the `DataGrid`.

Try this:

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid x:Name="grid_main" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <DataGrid x:Name="dg" Grid.Row="1">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test1" Width="100"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test2" Width="100"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test3" Width="100"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <DockPanel Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
            <Button x:Name="btn_loadSchema" Content="Load Schema" Grid.Row="0" Height="20" Width="85" DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
                        Margin="5" />
            <Button x:Name="btn_loadJSON" Content="Load JSON" Grid.Row="0" Height="20" Width="85" DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                        Margin="5" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <Button x:Name="btn_saveJSON" Content="Save JSON" Grid.Row="0" Height="20" Width="85" DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                        Margin="5" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <Label/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```